# What identifier of operator must be entered for assign shortcuts

Tags: interface

I have a couple of questions:

To configure a border selection to a left mouse button click and drag, I used the following example of parameter "Tweak".
[image]

After making these changes when I run this command, the subobjects selection occurs, those who fall within of the action zone the frame.
But now there is no possibility to make the deselection of certain parts of geometry (subobjects) by frame selection.
What do I need to do to deactivated part of geometry (subobjects) via hotkeys Alt +LMB?

And one more question:

In another post, is said that: The RNA value comes from the operator named above. Were you have entered "rotate view" needs to be the name of the operator to be run when the key/mouse combination is pressed. The standard operator to rotate the view would be view3d.rotate.

To get the value of a custom operator, you need to use the value of bl_idname defined in the operator you wish to use.

I do not understand exactly where and how should I use the value of "bl_idname" to get the value of the main operator?

Identifier of operator for the transformation tools (move, rotate, scale) has following view: "transform.rotate", etc.

However, to assign hot keys such tools as Move, Rotate and Scale must enter the following value: "view3d.enable_manipulyator". Why "enable_manipulyator"?
If I want to assign a hotkey to the "occluded geometry" button, What values do I need to enter?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please make different topics for each question

For border select you will have to create several entries for selection and deselection with tweak mouse with all the desired modifier keys, like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tweak</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Shit</kbd>+<kbd>Tweak</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>, ect. for example.

After that you have to additionally expand the *Border select* modal key map bellow any of the entries (they are all the same) and manually configure all options for selection, deselection, and canceling the operator.

[image: Border select keymap]

I use a similar setup myself, and it is a sort of a chore and a bit hit and miss manual work.

Word of advice, don't directly use <kbd>Left Mouse</kbd> or <kbd>Right Mouse</kbd> in your keymaps, when possible use <kbd>Select Mouse</kbd> or <kbd>Deselect Mouse</kbd> so the custom keymap remains dynamic and responds to general switch of selection with left or right click. Also make sure there are no conflicts as they may inexplicably make some key assignments nor work

Best way to know an operator name is to <kbd>Right Click</kbd> a button and choose one of the following options and search for hints there

- *Copy Python Command*
- *Copy Data Path*
- *Online Python Reference*
- *Assign Shortcut* (does it automatically)
- *Edit Source*

Some times it's also useful to search for that operator in the keymap list and see if there's one already assigned you can copy from.
Some buttons don't use an operator directly though, some times they need contexts, or toggle variables or call menus.

For toggling occluded geometry the operator has to be `wm.context_toggle` and the context is `space_data.use_occlude_geometry`

[image: Toggle Geometry Occlusion]