# Assigning HotKeys Using Python Commands

Tags: python

This question is an extension of this:
[What identifier of operator must be entered for assign shortcuts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63430/what-identifier-of-operator-must-be-entered-for-assign-shortcuts/63449#63449)

I did not understand how have copied `Python command` or `Data Path`
 available I could to determine that it is the context is `wm.context_toggle`
and attribute is `space_data.use_occlude_geometry`.

Could someone explain in more detail the thing about where the operators came from?

I found on the official website section initiated to the python, but I can not be guided in it

Answer (score 3):

Since i don't want to add another comment:

You can list all available operators via `Info Menu -> Help -> Operator Cheat Sheet` and look at the Text Block generated in the Text Editor

The operators are listed by category in this [section](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78_release/bpy.ops.html) (at the bottom of the page) of the API documentation.

If you drag down the Info Area you can see a history of recently used (registered) operators

You can hover over buttons with python tooltips enabled.

The context data is listed in this [section](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78_release/bpy.context.html) (available members depend on the area/mode)

The different spaces used by the corresponding editors/areas are listed in this [section](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78_release/bpy.types.Space.html) (subclasses - top of the page)

See also [Screen Elements](https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/introduction.html#screen-elements)

Answer (score 1):

Once again I'm not really I coder myself, so I don't know a definite answer for this.

I think I figured it out by trial and error myself, I looked up how other key maps were pre-configured by default, tested a few things and tried until it worked.

Googling for the operators is often useful too.

You can also look in Blender *Info Editor* (by default the header with the *File*, *Render*, *Window* and *Help* menus) if you expand the editor you will find above the menus is a message history. There and in the Online Python Manual you can find that it is a Boolean Property, and it toggles between `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Most other toggles that work like this are also probably Boolean Properties, for which you must toggle with the [`wm.context_toggle`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.wm.html?highlight=wm.context_toggle#bpy.ops.wm.context_toggle) operator.

Some others are actually *Enums* (enumeration of several possible predefined values) like for example the current 3D View Shading mode, and for those you use the operator [`wm.context_toggle_enum`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.wm.html?highlight=wm.context_toggle_enum#bpy.ops.wm.context_toggle_enum) instead. You can also learn this by inspecting other existing default keymaps.

Comment: Good. Let's imagine that I did not know the name of the operator for the tool  which I want to assign a hotkey ( "occlude_geometry").

Comment: It show up in the tooltip when you hover the button with the cursor

Comment: My actions:
1. Copies the selected line:
http://s11.postimg.org/6aonrikqb/7_M_X_pe_XN.jpg
2 and go to the Online Python Reference
ttp://s14.postimg.org/c5c5fynpt/7_M_X_pe_XN1.jpg
3. Search gives one correspondence:
http://s18.postimg.org/bd2rufr55/7_M_X_pe_XN.jpg
As you can see in the screenshot there is no name of the operator
Go on
In the header copy the name of the command:
http://s10.postimg.org/6eocwi095/7_M_X_pe_XN1.jpg

Comment: I believe all boolean type properties are always toggled with `wm.context_toggle` in the keymap. Like I said, inspect other available default keymaps and experiment. It's a trial and error process.

Comment: go to the Online Python Reference

http://s17.postimg.org/nmsewdhbz/7_M_X_pe_XN1.jpg

Trying to find needed information by 'Edit Source':

http://s22.postimg.org/bk0rx8mch/7_M_X_pe_XN.jpg

Also there is nothing

Another Tool:

If you imagine that I do not know the name of the transformation operator

http://s17.postimg.org/3l1c0i49r/7_M_X_pe_XN.jpg

That the above described actions do not lead to the desired result:

http://s13.postimg.org/x8v15qw3b/7_M_X_pe_XN.jpg

http://s4.postimg.org/qno2kgbdp/7_M_X_pe_XN.jpg

http://s13.postimg.org/ljrejx2yv/7_M_X_pe_XN.jpg

Comment: Maybe I'm looking for is not there???