# How to find the correct information for creating shortcut ?

Tags: shortcut

i really want to create shortcut by myself and im struling to find the correct code for what i want to create

this kind of code [image]

"screen.trigger_shadeless"

how do you find such information with anything inside of blender to create a shortcut ?

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What identifier of operator must be entered for assign shortcuts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63430/what-identifier-of-operator-must-be-entered-for-assign-shortcuts)

Answer (score 1):

right click ony (almost) any option and click **edit source**.

the name of the **operator** is what you need. (*n.b. I am no python expert so I may not have the right terminology or way of doing it*).

[image]

but it takes a bit of experience knowing what to search. depending on what are your needs, you can always right click and assign them on the fly. personally I never had a reason not do so.

Comment: thanks but it dont work anymore on 2.8 ?

Comment: as far as I can tell they do have it. not everyone though but not everyone has it also in blender 2.7x, it depends on the type of operations is doing. it may be easier if you could tell what exactly you need.

Comment: yes im trying to create shortcut with the new workspace in 2.8 , and i cant find the code anywhere , its workspace , the code fromt the old layout will not work

Comment: if there is something specific you need sorry I didn't understand.. you need a shortcut to create a new workspace? or you just want info on how you should do it in case you need it.. nothing specific just curiosity? if is the latter, well not everything is available or at least not so easy for the end user. if it is available in blender 2.79 but not 2.80 keep in mind that blender 2.80 is still in alpha stage so something may still be missing

Comment: I may have found out why you don't see edit source in blender 2.80. in the user preferences under the interface tab, you need to activate the option **Developer Extras**.

Comment: no still no python code for thoses new "workspaces" but i think the best way to find out is to ask there https://devtalk.blender.org/c/python which i did

Comment: ok so maybe I finally understood what you need! you need a shortcut to scroll the new workspace like LAYOUT MODELING SCULPTING etc etc. if is that you can just press CTRL PAGE UP / PAGE DOWN. the operator name for that is screen.workspace_cycle

Comment: yes but this is cycling trough the modes , i want a shortcut to set the active workspace to a specific designed workspace

which is "bpy.context.window.workspace = bpy.data.workspaces["MyWorkspace"]"

thanks for your dedication by the way :)

Answer (score 0):

theres few possibilities :

1) right click "copy python command" but you need to have in the user pref / interface : python tooltips / devs extra , otherwise you will no see it

2) right click "see online python reference" but you need to have in the user pref / interface : python tooltips / devs extra , otherwise you will no see it

3) see in the info editor what python code you just did

Comment: Not the data path, In this case it is the operator name   Use 
"Copy Python Command".  See comment on question re duplicate.