# Disable Inset's 'Right Click To Cancel'

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-view

I Would like to assign an Inset tool on Ctrl+Shift+RMB and everything is fine except that when I release RMB tool cancels inself due to its own parameter (release RMB to cancel)

[Video Example](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/4gdenxvrdppo175/2018-11-28_04-03-27.mp4)

Is there any way to disable 'RMB to cancel' in that specific tool?

Some tools like Knife do have a Modal Maps which allow to set 'No Operation' state to cirtain circumstances like mine, where 'RMB-Release'should Confirm operation instead of Canceling it.

I have just started to use Blender and concidering migration from Modo and the most critical parameter for me is customization

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63430/what-identifier-of-operator-must-be-entered-for-assign-shortcuts/63449#63449

Comment: Inset does not have modal map parameters. i specificly pointed that out in my initial question